# Formset header only?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to have just the header of a form set exemple :

```
    CaracFormSet = formset_factory(CaracForm, extra=0)
    CaracFormSet = CaracFormSet(prefix='carac',initial=initial)
```

i just want the header how to do that ?

```
    print CaracFormSet. what ?
```

here is the header of my formset :

```
    <input type="hidden" name="carac-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_carac-TOTAL_FORMS
    " /><input type="hidden" name="carac-INITIAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_carac-INITI
    AL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="carac-MAX_NUM_FORMS" id="id_carac-MAX_NUM
    _FORMS" />
```

Regards
Bussiere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [management_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform)

```
print CaracFormSet.management_form
```